# List bullets still how although in CSS I put "list-style:none"

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a CSS problem on this page: http://www.fastclickad.com/ask-for-your-free-seo-analysis/

For some reason, bullets still show although I inserted in the style sheet several instructions so the list styles don't inherit from the theme.

When I "inspect element" with google Chrome everything seems to go smooth, except the bullets still show!

Can you help me?

Comment: There are no list bullets visible on the page on Chrome, Firefox, IE.

Answer (score 0):

You have a border specified which, if removed, prevents the arrow:

```
.aritclecontent ul li::before, .sidebarwidget ul li::before {
  border-left: solid #0473B2;
}
```

So you'll need to do something like:

```
.gform_body ul li:before {
  border-left:none!important;
}
```

The `!important` could be frowned upon, so you might wish to analyse your styles and refactor accordingly to remove the need for using it, if indeed it is necessary.

Comment: Thank you Grant! You got it!

I am still unsure why the arrow was showing up because of this border.

Thanks again!

Comment: Just for the sake of clarification: the arrow is being created with pseudo-content. It's a fairly common technique, whereby a `:before` element is applied with a width and height of zero. Giving it a coloured border on one side creates a triangle. As @Grant Thomas pointed out, you can override this by specifying `border-left:none` on the `:before` element, or you can remove the rules which originally created it, which would be cleaner.
You can find out more about this technique by reading [this article](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/)

Answer (score -1):

try this ..

```
 list-style-type: none;
```